# Sum every scores using php oracle

Tags: javascript, php, html, oracle

I have created 5 surveys that each have 3 radio buttons. Each button can parse a value and each survey has its own form. So how do I sum all the scores by adding each value from each form and then send the sum of the scores to a database.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show code and effort

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP sessions or maybe even a database with all the answers submitted and the score awarded for them.

```
<?php

session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['score']))
{
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}

$userAnswer = $_POST['answer'] //radio button name

if($userAnswer == $correctAnswer) //get the $correctAnswer from a database or define it before this. 
{
    $_SESSION['score'] += 10; //points
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['score'] -= 5; //negative score for a wrong answer maybe?
}

?>
```

This should be the basic logic behind using sessions for managing the score.

Refrain from putting the score on the client-side as it can be manipulated easily.

Comment: @mplungjan I edited the answer with sample code. Thank you.